# Html video + jquery not working on android tablet

Tags: android, jquery, html, video

I have a web page which plays a video. My code as follows:

**HTML**

```
<video id="intro-vid" autobuffer style="min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" >
  <source src="Videos/intro.mp4">
</video>
```

**JQuery**

```
try {
  alert('inside try');
  $('#intro-vid')[0].play();
} catch(Err) {
  alert(Err.message);
}
```

I have tried it in my pc and it is working fine. I have copied my files into android device and tried to work from there it is not working. **I am getting inside try alert but video not playing**. please guide me why it is not working?

I am using **Dell tab Venue 7  and android version 4.4.4 and latest Google chrome browser**

Fiddle [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/AUSNu/365/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not play video from code on mobile devices it must be after some user intercation such as click or mouse down...etc

Comment: ok suppose it on click. How can I do that? After play this it should close automatically. Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: I do not know how to make fiddle but you put a div above the video and on click on the div play video and hide the div and make an event on video ends remove it using .html('')

Comment: @ Emad Morris Zedan fiddle added above. please check it and update code and update me buddy. please i am stuck on this for couple of days.

Comment: @ Emad Morris Zedan  just edit the fiddle and click update pencil above and just copy me the link it will be enough.

Comment: is this working with you, if yes please mark my answer as the answer of the question

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy